# Single page app: authorization code grant with OAuth2

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, authorization, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

I am following the tutorial [Spring Boot and OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/).
I need some insight on the server-based OAuth2 flow when front end and backend are on the different servers.

According to the tutorial backend provides /login/facebook endpoint which essentially redirects to the facebook and after authorization - back to the redirect url. It works fine when frontend is part of backend deployment. However when I split frontend and backend to different application I am facing issues and need insight on doing things right.

- Let's assume FE is localhost:3000 and my-super-duper-site.com
- Let's assume BE is localhost:8080 and not visible to public
- Let's assume FE is using angular2 and BE using spring boot

Here how I see/done it now:

1. User opens fronend and navigates to login page there
2. There is a link to authorize through the facebook. It looks that it
   should actually point to a backend /login/facebook url, but backend
   will not be visible to public, so I added a proxy to the FE which
   translates FE login url to the BE login url under the hood. Is that
   correct?
3. Once backend login endpoint hit - it redirects the user to the authorization server where the user authorizes my app and should redirect the user to a redirect url with the token, right?
4. In my case the redirect url should be a FE page, just becuase backend is not visible to public. So, looks like I get the token on the FE side and should put the token into each FE->BE request. Is it the way how it should work?
5. The redirect to FE will also cause single page app to reload itself and I don't think there is a way to avoid that..
6. The last issue is: if the user was not authenticated and navigated to an url, say, /myapp/order?id=1 I would like the login dialog to be shown to user and once authorized I would like the user to be redirected back to the /myapp/order?id=1. Is it possible?

I know that there is client-side flow, but I don't want to keep secret on the client (hello reverse engineering) and that's what the server-flow was created for.

Comment: Same issue, hope someone resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description it seems you've implemented OAuth to authenticate your users from facebook. You must have created an OAuth client at facebook.

The OAuth2.0 Authorization Code Grant flow works this way

```
 +--------+                               +---------------+
 |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ->|   Resource    |
 |        |                               |     Owner     |
 |        |<-(B)-- Authorization Grant ---|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(C)-- Authorization Grant -->| Authorization |
 |Your BE |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(D)----- Access Token -------|   Facebook    |
 | Client |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(E)----- Access Token ------>|    Resource   |
 |        |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(F)--- Protected Resource ---|               |
 +--------+                               +---------------+
```

It's tricky in case of Client -> Server model specially in SPA's.

How you handle that.

1. Create your OAuth2.0 client configure the redirect uri to your
   backend.
2. Intercept the redirect uri. The moment you get the token you can pass the  token to your frontend server through SSE Emitter or you can also poll specific endpoint which checks the token availibility. When you find it you send in the response.